# nonetype object is not callable как исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Зациклено две строки кода, цикл проходит примерно 10 раз, после появляется ошибка.

Код:

```
random_choice=(random.choice(equation_number))
random_choice()
```

Ошибка:

> "nonetype" object is not callable

Comment: Что такое `equation_number`? Как Вы представляете себе логику работы Вашей программы?

Comment: это массив похоже я понял там 198символов слишком много

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нужно просто убрать скобки, random_choice - это не функция, а переменная.

```
random_choice=(random.choice(equation_number))
print(random_choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
random_choice=(random.choice(equation_number))
```

- Или в переменной `random_choice` будет случайный элемент списка `equation_number`, т.е. в вашем случае число. Тогда команда `random_choice()` выдает ошибку

  > TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

  или

  > TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
- Или список `equation_number` *пустой*, и уже `random.choice(equation_number)` выдает ошибку

  > IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

**В ни коем случае вы не получите ошибку**

> "nonetype" object is not callable

как вы пишете — эта ошибка может быть связана только **с другой частей вашей программы**.

Comment: Ошибка в этой части программы: `random_choice()` вернет ошибку, если исходный список состоит не из функций (или callable объектов).